# Why does IEnumerable.ToList produce new objects

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class TestClass
{
   public int Num { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<TestClass> originalEnumerable
   = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).
                Select(x => new TestClass() { Num = x, Name = x.ToString() });

List<TestClass> listFromEnumerable = originalEnumerable.ToList();

// false
bool test = ReferenceEquals(listFromEnumerable[0], originalEnumerable.ElementAt(0));
```

If I modify the copied object the original does not change.

I understand from this that `System.Linq.IEnumerable<T>` collections will always produce new objects even though they are reference types when calling `ToList()`/`ToArray()`? Am I missing something as other SO questions are insistent only references are copied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the fact, that `Enumerable.Range` is lazy, so this line actually produce nothing but in-memory query definition:

```
IEnumerable<TestClass> originalEnumerable
   = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).
                Select(x => new TestClass() { Num = x, Name = x.ToString() });
```

Calling `ToList()` fires the query and creates list with new items:

```
List<TestClass> listFromEnumerable = originalEnumerable.ToList();
```

Calling `originalEnumerable.ElementAt(0)` here

```
bool test = ReferenceEquals(listFromEnumerable[0], originalEnumerable.ElementAt(0));
```

fires the query again, and produces yet another new items.

**Update**

So you should say, that `Enumerable.Range` produces new items, not `ToList()`.

If your source collection would be already evaluated (e.g. `TestClass[]` array) `ToList()` won't create new items:

```
IEnumerable<TestClass> originalEnumerable
   = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).
                Select(x => new TestClass() { Num = x, Name = x.ToString() })
                .ToArray();

List<TestClass> listFromEnumerable = originalEnumerable.ToList();

// true
bool test = ReferenceEquals(listFromEnumerable[0], originalEnumerable[0]);
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually, the reason this is false is because your enumerable actually gets enumerated *twice*, once in the call `originalEnumerable.ToList()`, and a second time when you invoke `originalEnumerable.ElementAt(0)`.

Since it enumerates twice, it ends up creating new objects each time it is enumerated.

Comment: And if you have ReSharper installed, it will even underline the methods enumerating the IEnumerable and tell you about this, which is pretty handy. In nasty scenarios, multiple (unnecessary) enumeration might cost a lot of time.